# Do static objective-c classes have to subclass NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, subclassing, nsobject, nsinvocation

In my objective-c project, I have a weird, lets say, *feature* I have a class, like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Convert /* : NSObject */ // <--- is that necessary? 

+(int) toInt:(id) obj;

@end

@implementation Convert

+(int) toInt:(id) obj
{
     return [obj intValue];
}

@end
```

What happens is, when I step through the code It works fine, but I get a cryptic error in the console (even though code is completely fine, works as expected):

```
2010-11-03 09:35:49.422 Tests[14066:5f03] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x9e424 of class 'Convert' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2010-11-03 09:35:49.422 Tests[14066:5f03] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x9e424 of class 'Convert' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

Yet, even when It says abort, the code still works. However, when I run it without stepping through those lines of code, it aborts. What Is happening and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "yes".

Or more specifically, the runtime expects objects to conform to the `NSObject` protocol, and the simplest way to do this is by making sure your objects inherit from the `NSObject` class.